# Как установить выбранный диапазон дат по умолчанию?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Использую эту библиотеку для выбора диапазона дат: [ссылка](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/index-ru.html)

Метод `range: true`

Хочу сделать чтобы по умолчанию (при открытии календарика) были выбраны даты с сегодняшней и по +7 дней.

Не нашел в документации этого... Может я был не очень внимателен..

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: а если просто в input дописать value="08.08.2019 - 17.08.2019" ?

Comment: @splash58 пробовал. не срабатывает

Comment: а метод  `selectDate` из раздела API не подходит для данных целей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как выше в комменте написали там есть [selectDate](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/index-ru.html). Вот грубый пример:

```js
$(function() {
  var myDate = new Date();
  var spanDay = myDate.getDate();
  myDate.setDate(spanDay + 7);
  var datepicker = $('#datepick').datepicker().data('datepicker'),
    $picker = $('#datepick');
  $picker.datepicker({
    range: true,
    language: 'ru',
    autoClose: true
  });

  $picker.data('datepicker').selectDate([new Date(), new Date(myDate)]);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='datepick' />
```

Comment: выбирать как-то неудобно стало

Comment: Поправил, сейчас норм вроде

Comment: Теперь не скрывает календарь, даже если  на инпут наступить. надо куда-то в сторону тыкать. или это правильно?

Comment: Ну вернул `autoClose` , теперь при закрывается :-)

Comment: не знаю, как автору вопроса, а мне на +1 понравилось :)

Comment: @splash58 спасибо, наконец-таки больше 1000 теперь ^_^

Comment: заходите, как будет 1995 :)